# How can I align arrows' labels into readable place?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am having difficulty to align label of arrows into compact and readable position. In drawing program I can easily put the text of arrow into readable places but its much difficult in `tikz`. Please see output of the wanted figure:

[image]

---

My simple approach:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,shape aspect=1]
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        arrow/.style={->, >=stealth, very thick},
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \node[block] (A) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum height=2.5cm,minimum width=2cm]{C};
    \node[block] at (140:7) (B) [rectangle, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm]{Some Program} ;
    \node[block] at (40:7) (C) [rectangle, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=3cm]{Some Program A};
    \node[block] at (90:5) (D) [circle, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm]{D};
    \draw [arrow] (B) -- node[below] {latex is awesome, latex is awesome} (A) ;
    \draw [arrow] (C) -- node[below] {latex is awesome, latex is awesome} (A);
    \draw [arrow] (B) -- node[above] {latex is awesome} (D);
    \draw [arrow] (C) -- node[above] {latex is awesome} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I am unable to coordinate the label of arrows to the correct position. Add `->` style into arrows.

Comment: First, you need to use only one pair of brackets after `\begin{tikzpicture}`. That's why your arrows don't have tips. Then you may need to use `[above left]` for example, instead of `[above]` to place your labels. You also can place your labels not in the middle of your arrow but anywhere you want like this: `\draw[arrow] (A) -- (B) node[above left, pos=0.75] {your text}`. Those adjustements should suffice.

Comment: Can the caption width limited as well?

Comment: @alper Caption width can be set through e.g.: `\draw[arrow] (A) -- (B) node[text width=2cm,above left, pos=0.75] {your text}`

Comment: can also `pos` make the alignment in the x-axis? seems like it shift the caption in y-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use relative coordinates, library `quotes` for edge labels (quotes), defined picture's elements as its options and colored nodes:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 33mm,
every edge/.style = {draw, {Stealth[scale=0.8]}-{Stealth[scale=0.8]}, semithick,
                     shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, inner xsep=-1em, 
                            text width=9em, align=center},
         C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=yellow!30, minimum size=5ex},
        DB/.style = {cylinder, shape aspect=0.5,
                     shape border rotate=90,
                     draw, fill=orange!30,
                     minimum width=16mm, minimum height=8mm, inner sep=1mm, align=center,
                    },
      mpnv/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1,
                     draw, fill=cyan!30, inner sep=1pt,
                     text width=7em, align=flush center},
         N/.style = {draw, fill=olive!30, minimum width=7em, minimum height=5ex},
                        ]
\node (A)   [N]                 {Some Program} ;
\node (D)   [C, right=of A]     {D};
\node (C)   [mpnv=3, right=of D,
             anchor=one west]  {Some Program A
                                 \nodepart{two}     Some Program B
                                 \nodepart{three}   Some Program C
                                 };
\node (DB)  [DB, below=of D]    {C};
%
\draw   (A)     edge ["latex is awesome"]   (D)
        (D)     edge ["latex is awesome"]   (C.one west)
        (A)     edge ["{latex is awesome,
                       latex is awesome}" ']   (DB)
        (DB)    edge ["{latex is awesome,
                        latex is awesome}" ']   (C.three west)
                   ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**
Regarding your comment, you can use suggestion of @unknow (see her/his comment below) or consider my comment below and accordingly slightly rewrite above propose MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 23mm,                                      % <---
  base/.style = {font=\footnotesize, draw, fill=#1,                 % <---
                 text width=7em, align=flush center,                % <---
                 minimum height=8mm},                               % <---
every edge/.style = {draw, {Stealth[scale=0.8]}-{Stealth[scale=0.8]}, semithick,
                     shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\scriptsize, inner xsep=0pt, 
                            text width=6em, align=flush center},    % <---
         C/.style = {circle, base=yellow!30, text width =8mm=5ex},
        DB/.style = {cylinder, shape aspect=0.3,                    % <---
                     shape border rotate=90,
                     base=orange!30,                                % <---
                     text width=16mm, inner sep=1mm, align=center,
                    },
      mpnv/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1,
                     base=cyan!30},                  % <---
         N/.style = {base=olive!30},
                        ]
\node (A)   [N]                 {Some Program} ;
\node (D)   [C, right=of A]     {D};
\node (C)   [mpnv=3, right=of D,
             anchor=one west]  {Some Program A
                                 \nodepart{two}     Some Program B
                                 \nodepart{three}   Some Program C
                                 };
\node (DB)  [DB, below=of D]    {C};
%
\draw   (A)     edge ["latex is\\ awesome"]   (D)
        (D)     edge ["latex is\\ awesome"]   (C.one west)
        (A)     edge ["{latex is awesome,
                       latex is awesome}" ']   (DB)
        (DB)    edge ["{latex is awesome,
                        latex is awesome}" ']   (C.three west)
                   ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All changes in comparison to the first MWE are marked in code by `% <---`. Beside changes font sizes, are changed distanced between nodes and at horizontal edges and edge quotes broken into two lines. Consequently image can be narrower -- by reducing node distance as I did in above MWE.

In the case, that you like to have all text in script size, in above MWE you only need to change in `base` style define font size: `font=\scriptsize` or consider @unknown suggestion and from style remove all font size definitions.

[image]

**Addendum (2):**
In cases, that you like to have edge quotes above and below edge, you ca split it in two parts and for one of the use `swap` or its shortcut `'`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 23mm,                                      % <---
  base/.style = {font=\footnotesize, draw, fill=#1,                 % <---
                 text width=7em, align=flush center,                % <---
                 minimum height=8mm},                               % <---
every edge/.style = {draw, {Stealth[scale=0.8]}-{Stealth[scale=0.8]}, semithick,
                     shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\scriptsize, inner xsep=0pt,
                            TW=#1, align=flush center},             
         C/.style = {circle, base=yellow!30, text width =8mm=5ex},
        DB/.style = {cylinder, shape aspect=0.3,                    
                     shape border rotate=90,
                     base=orange!30,                                
                     text width=16mm, inner sep=1mm, align=center,
                    },
      mpnv/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1,
                     base=cyan!30},                  
         N/.style = {base=olive!30},
        TW/.style = {text width=#1},
      TW/.default = {6em}
                        ]
\node (A)   [N]                 {Some Program} ;
\node (D)   [C, right=of A]     {D};
\node (C)   [mpnv=3, right=of D,
             anchor=one west]  {Some Program A
                                 \nodepart{two}     Some Program B
                                 \nodepart{three}   Some Program C
                                 };
\node (DB)  [DB, below=of D]    {C};
%
\draw   (A)     edge ["latex is\\ awesome",
                      "{here is more\\ text;
                       but do such long labels make any sense?}" ' ]   (D)    % <---
        (D)     edge ["latex is\\ awesome"]   (C.one west)
        (A)     edge ["{latex is awesome,
                       latex is awesome}" ']   (DB)
        (DB)    edge ["{latex is awesome,
                        latex is awesome}" '
                      ]   (C.three west)
                   ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or in this special case when number of label text is evem you can define anchor for it:

```
\draw   (A)     edge ["{latex is\\ awesome,
                        here is more\\ text;
                        but do such long labels make any sense?}" 
                        anchor=center ]   (D)
...
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to apply `\scriptsize` for all font?

Comment: @alper You can use `every node/.style = {font=\scriptsize}`.

Comment: @alper, from your question follows, that all text in image have the same -- normal -- size of fonts. According to my taste I reduce font at edge quotes to `\footnotesize`. I wouldn't recommend to have all text in `\scriptsize` , but it is up to you. See addendum to answer.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the edit. I was trying to make it fit into double-column; should I re-size it or change the `node distance = 22mm and 23mm` to make it. PS: sorry for the additional questions

Comment: Can also `text width=6em` be wider for the text on the south-east, when I increase it, position of the `latex is awesome` at top misplaced.

Comment: @alper, in answer I show only a skeleton, how your image can be drawn. All parameters in styles definitions you can change according to your taste. They can be overwritten  locally too

Comment: the configuration for the labels are defined at top, which applies to all labels I believe. How can I overwrite labels at the bottom letting them to have wider width (assume their text will be longer)

Comment: @alper, by option `swap` or its short case `'` as is used in answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's a quick review of your code to make what we said clear:

[image: labels alignment]

`pos=0.75`means place the node at 75% of the line length.

`text width=3cm` is pretty obvious and allows you to write on multiple lines.

I deleted the `[block]` style that you didn't define

Some elements remain to be made, but this was not your main question so I let them like this, maybe you could ask another questino about those specific items (split rectengle on the right, for example).

Feel free to comment and discuss.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        shape aspect=1,
        arrow/.style={->, >=stealth, very thick,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt},
        ]
        \node (A) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum height=2.5cm,minimum width=2cm]{C};
        \node at (140:7) (B) [rectangle, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm]{Some Program} ;
        \node at (40:7) (C) [rectangle, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=3cm]{Some Program A};
        \node at (90:5) (D) [circle, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm]{D};
        
    
        \draw [arrow] (B) -- (A) node[left=3mm, text width=2.7cm,align=center,red,pos=0.75] {latex is awesome, latex is awesome} ;
        
        \draw [arrow] (C) -- (A) node[right=3mm, text width=2.7cm,align=center,blue,pos=0.75] {latex is awesome, latex is awesome} ;
        
        \draw [arrow] (B) -- (D) node[above, text width=1.5cm,align=center,orange,pos=0.35] {latex is awesome} ;
        
        \draw [arrow] (C) -- (D) node[above, text width=1.5cm,align=center,pink,pos=0.35] {latex is awesome} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want the rectangle split, use this line:

```
\node at (40:7) (C) [rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=3cm]{Some Program A \nodepart{two} Some Program B \nodepart{three} Some Program C};
```

[image: rectangle split]

Comment: Just on the rectangle right corner, I have to create additional rectangle below like the one figore on my question. For that should I create a new node as rectange below on the existing rectange that exists or inside the rectangle should I draw a horizontal line inside

Comment: Like I said, it exists an option known as `rectangle split` that you can use for this. I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :-) I was trying to create new node but it required many trial-error to find its correct location