# How can I draw cloud figure behind a cyclinder?

Tags: tikz-pgf, cloud

I am trying to draw a cloud figure in the background of a cylinder. Original [example](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/cloud-network_1269774?term=cloud%20storage&page=1&position=68&page=1&position=68&related_id=1269774), sorry I was not able to find the cylinder version of it:

[image]

Latex version of the wanted figure:

[image]

---

What I have as follows, cloud is taken from the following [answer for Asymmetric cloud shape in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448414/127048):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\AsymCloud}[3]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={#1},scale=#3]
        \draw (-1.6,-0.7) .. controls (-2.3,-1.1)
        and (-2.7,0.3) .. (-1.7,0.3)coordinate(asy1) .. controls (-1.6,0.7)
        and (-1.2,0.9) .. (-0.8,0.7) .. controls (-0.5,1.5)
        and (0.6,1.3) .. (0.7,0.5) .. controls (1.5,0.4)
        and (1.2,-1) .. (0.4,-0.6)coordinate(asy2) .. controls (0.2,-1)
        and (-0.2,-1) .. (-0.5,-0.7) .. controls (-0.9,-1)
        and (-1.3,-1) .. cycle;
        \node at ($(asy1)!0.5!(asy2)$) {#2};
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \AsymCloud{(0,1)}{}{1} at (0,1)
    %\AsymCloud{coordinate}{text}{scale factor}
    \node[text width=1cm,text centered] (A) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum height=0.5cm,minimum
width=0.5cm, shape
        aspect=0.4,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt}]{\scriptsize{Cloud Storage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I was not able to aligh cloud to correct place and draw it in the background. If possible I want to define cloud as a `node`.

its output:

[image]

Related:

- [How can I wrap a text in a rectange inside a cloud?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650122/127048)

Comment: Where does `execute at begin node=...` come from? -For me that seems like a very extreme way to do a simple thing.

Comment: Ah original figure is coming from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646749/127048 ; where I had to connect the cylinder using arrows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\AsymCloud}[3]{
\begin{scope}[shift={#1},scale=#3]
\draw (-1.6,-0.7) .. controls (-2.3,-1.1)
and (-2.7,0.3) .. (-1.7,0.3)coordinate(asy1) .. controls (-1.6,0.7)
and (-1.2,0.9) .. (-0.8,0.7) .. controls (-0.5,1.5)
and (0.6,1.3) .. (0.7,0.5) .. controls (1.5,0.4)
and (1.2,-1) .. (0.4,-0.6)coordinate(asy2) .. controls (0.2,-1)
and (-0.2,-1) .. (-0.5,-0.7) .. controls (-0.9,-1)
and (-1.3,-1) .. cycle;
\path (asy1) -- (asy2) node[pos=0.5] {#2};
\end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\AsymCloud{(0.3,0.8)}{}{0.8}
\node[text width=1cm, text centered, cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw, minimum height=0.5cm, minimum
width=0.5cm, shape aspect=0.4, font={\scriptsize\baselineskip=8pt}, fill=white, preaction={draw, white, line width=15pt}]{Cloud Storage};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A cloud with a cylinder and text]

Comment: Is it possible to scale cloud smaller?

Comment: Also idk but Cloud Storage is written having new line in between when I try your code

Comment: I mistakenly left `\baselineskip=18pt` for testing - now changed back to `8pt`. The scaling of the cloud is controlled by the third parameter - try  `\AsymCloud{(0.3,0.8)}{}{0.7}`

Comment: sorry I forget to ask in my question, is it possible to make line of the cloud little bit thicker?

Comment: You can add the option `thick`, `very thick`, `ultra thick` or `line width=5pt`.

Answer (score 3):

A bit more parameterization.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, shapes}

% \AsymCloud{<name of a cylinder node>}
\newcommand{\AsymCloud}[1]{
    % helper rectangle to show the real bounding box of cylinder
    % \draw[red] (#1.bottom -| #1.after bottom) rectangle 
    %            (#1.top    -| #1.after top);
    \draw[shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt]
        let \p1=(#1.bottom -| #1.after bottom), % real south east == (\x1, \y1)
            \p2=(#1.top -| #1.after top),       % real north west == (\x2, \y2)
            \p3=($ (\p2) - (\p1) $)             % total size      == (\x3, \y3)
        in (\x2, \y1+.5*\y3) % real west 
            arc[start angle=-80, delta angle=150, radius=.3*\y3]
            arc[start angle=0,   delta angle=150, radius=.5*\x3]
            arc[start angle=60,  delta angle=150, radius=.1*\x3+.1*\y3]
            arc[start angle=120, delta angle=150, radius=.2*\y3+.1*\x3]
          ;
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every cylinder node/.style={
    draw,
    text centered, text width=1cm,
    node font=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt}\scriptsize,
    shape aspect=0.4
}]
    \node[shape border rotate=90, minimum height=0.5cm, cylinder]
      (A) {Cloud Storage};
    \AsymCloud{A}

    \node[shape border rotate=90, minimum height=2.5cm, cylinder]
      at (3,0) (B) {Cloud Storage};
    \AsymCloud{B}

    \node[shape border rotate=90, minimum width=2.5cm, cylinder]
      at (7,0) (C) {Cloud Storage};
    \AsymCloud{C}
    
    \node[shape border rotate=90, minimum size=2.5cm, cylinder]
      at (11,0) (D) {Cloud Storage};
    \AsymCloud{D}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the all combinations. Is it possible to make cloud's left side pop-up half circle little bit more wider?

Comment: @alper Can't say it's impossible, but currently I don't have the time to really solve such a system of linear equations. Current parameters are just guessing with some luck.

Comment: Like on the second image it is in the same size as the top half circle but when the cloud get larger like the one on the rightest cloud, left cloud remains same size which seems much smaller